# How can I get the post content displayed in a text field that allows to edit posts?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, editor

I replaced my WordPress TinyMCE editor with a custom textarea field. Everything works well when saving the post but whenever I want to edit the post, the textarea field goes blank.

I just want to ask if there is any hook I have to call to make the post display for editing in the textarea field.

If there is any hook, please guide me.

Thanks.